# Quick Replies - Suggestion in Dialogflow (using Fulfillment)

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm new to Dialogflow Fulfillment. I don't know how to change the title of Quick Replies. It always show: "Choose an item".

I viewed the "suggestions-response.js" and I saw an example:

```
@example
   * let suggestion = new Suggestion('suggestion');
   * const anotherSuggestion = new Suggestion({
   *     title: 'Choose an item:',
   *     reply: 'suggestion',
   *     platform: 'FACEBOOK'
   * });
```

But when I tried to use it in my code:

```
const quickReplies1 = new Suggestion({
    title: "What do you want to do?",
    reply: "Next",
    platform: 'FACEBOOK'
})
quickReplies1.addReply_("Cancle");
agent.add(quickReplies1);
```

It didn't work, "Next" and "Cancle" were ok, but the title still was "Choose an item".

Edit:
My full code just for testing is:

```
const {Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

function welcome(agent)
{
  const quickReplies1 = new Suggestion({
    title: "What do you want to do?",
    reply: "Next",
    platform: 'FACEBOOK'
  })
  quickReplies1.addReply_("Cancel");

  agent.add(quickReplies1);
}
```

In package.json:

```
"dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1"
```

And the result that I receive in my chatbot ( on Facebook Messenger):

```
Choose an item
What do you want to do     -     Cancel (*2 quick replies)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're appending .addReply_ to the correct object? The way you have your code now, agent.add(quickReplies1) should definitely work. It would help if you included the full source code because there could be something else going on there that's not apart of the example you included..

Good luck!

Comment: I've edited my full code, I use "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1" for sending audio files.
Many thanks.